# KVM add public IP to a virtual machine

Tags: kvm-virtualization, cloud, ip

I got a new dedicated server and installed KVM on it. I've created a virtual machine but I got some problems managing public IP to that VM. In addition, the Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS server has installed on the host VM.

---

### The host network details

`ifconfig`:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 88.44.31.30  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe81::b62e:99fd:fecd:fd13  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:4f8:232:1b07::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b2:2e:99:fb:3b:aa  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2934329  bytes 1525163180 (1.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2799211  bytes 3794187248 (3.7 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0x51200000-51220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 246437  bytes 3598125972 (3.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 246437  bytes 3598125972 (3.5 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:53:0b:a6:6f:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15954  bytes 1189621 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27979  bytes 283208200 (283.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe81::fc50:56af:fbb0:6aa4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:50:56:00:67:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 870  bytes 100801 (100.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21441  bytes 2188836 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 88.44.31.30/32
        - 2a02:4f8:232:1b07::2/64
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 88.44.31.1
      gateway6: fe81::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 213.133.98.98
          - 213.133.99.99
          - 213.133.100.100
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::abd:9912
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::abd:1022
          - 2a01:4f8:0:1::abd:9844
```

`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         88.44.31.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

---

### The VM network details

`ifconfig`:

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.178  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        inet6 fe81::fc50:bbaf:fab0:6aa5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:bb:56:aa:67:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 797  bytes 302823 (302.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 590  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 165  bytes 19312 (19.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 90  bytes 6966 (6.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 6966 (6.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0
192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp1s0
```

---

The ISP gives me the following address:

```
address 88.44.31.10
netmask 255.255.255.224
gateway 88.44.31.1
```

Therefore, I need to access the VM from the outside/internet by `88.44.31.10` but dunno how to configure the host and the VM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-setup-bridge-networking-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-20-04-9c560b3e3991

Comment: You may refer to this page for creating a network bridge on your host: https://www.x386.xyz/index.php/2021/01/06/kvm-on-ubuntu-server-1/ . Install your VM using that network bridge and give it IP as given by your ISP. There is a good chance that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a bridge on your external interface. Then you can have an device&IP on that bridge for your host, but also connect your guest to it to work on the same externally facing network.

An example of such a configuration can be found on the [netplan.io example](https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges) page.

You can later on go bigger considering OpenVswitch as an alternative, but that will be more complex and therefore only useful if you need it's advanced features.